# Closing document after saving it with wdFormatDocument format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a longer code and in the final part there is an ActiveX button for saving and closing the file. Also, for efficiency, I've added an `vbYesNo` command for creating a new document based on the template in use.

**The code:**

```
Sub macrosave ()
Dim doc As Document
Dim strDosar As String
Dim Ret As Variant
Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
strDosar = Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
Ret = MsgBox("Do you want to create a new document?", vbYesNo)
    If Ret = vbYes Then
    Documents.Add Template:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Name
     End If
doc.SaveAs "\\server\Public\" & strDosar & ".doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument = 0
doc.Close
End Sub
```

If I click yes, a new document is created, the last one is saved and closed afterwards.
If I click no, the active document is saved, but it is not closed afterwards.

I suspect it has something to do with the file format (`wdFormatDocument`) because this way it eliminates all VBA codes.

The file format is needed because I want to get rid of all content controls after saving the file.
Why `doc.Close` is not being executed in the second case and what are my options in order to achieve the purpose?

Comment: Which version of. Word is this running in?

Comment: It's Microsoft Word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This argument is invalid:
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument = 0

Perhaps:

```
Sub macrosave()
Dim doc As Document, strDosar As String, Ret As Variant
Set doc = ActiveDocument
strDosar = Split(doc.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
Ret = MsgBox("Do you want to create a new document?", vbYesNo)
If Ret = vbYes Then Documents.Add Template:=doc.AttachedTemplate.FullName
doc.SaveAs "\\server\Public\" & strDosar & ".doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
doc.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: If am using `Template:=doc.AttachedTemplate` I get `Runtype error 13: Type mismatch`. Instead, I have used `Template:=doc.AttachedTemplate.Path & Application.PathSeparator & doc.AttachedTemplate.Name`. Also, the code was working even with `FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument = 0` that's why I didn't bother to remove it but I did now as it's redundant. Strangely, if I click yes in the `Ret` message box and run the macro for the newly created document, it actually makes the word not responsive and it closes because of that (when I open the document that was saved, it says that it was repaired).

Comment: I've identified that the cause of the program being not responsive was the removal of `=0`. If I keep `=0` the documents are saved without vba code (there is no template attached to the document) but if I remove it, the documents still have the template attached to the document.

Comment: I've edited the code slightly: Documents.Add Template:=doc.AttachedTemplate.FullName

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from a disagreement between the file extension - `doc` and the specified file format `wdFormatDocument`.

Starting with Word 2007 the default file format (`wdFormatDocument`) refers to the Word Open XML file format, `docx`. To save as the `doc` file format requires using `wdFormatDocument97`. The reason it may have intermittently worked is because the numerical value of this enumeration is `0`.

Try

```
doc.SaveAs "\\server\Public\" & strDosar & ".doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument97
```

*Or* change the extension to `docx`

```
doc.SaveAs "\\server\Public\" & strDosar & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
```

*However* `docx` will not remove the content controls the next time the document is opened. (The `doc` format will because content controls were introduced at the same time as the new file format, so they aren't supported in the old format.)

If the additional purpose is " it eliminates all VBA codes" then it would make sense to change the attached template before closing the document to Normal.dotm. This removes the link to the attached template and has the added advantage that the document will "find" its template no matter who opens it, later. (When the attached template is not present it can delay opening by a considerable time under some circumstances.)

```
doc.AttachedTemplate = NormalTemplate
```

Note that it will also make things simpler to pick up the file path using the `FullName` poperty of the template:

```
Documents.Add Template:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
```

Comment: My purpose is to eliminate all VBA codes for the saved documents and close them, not for the document that is currently editing. If I change to Normal template before save command, the code no longer runs and the file isn't saved. After saving the document, changing the template modifies the document so it has to be saved again. If I don't switch to Normal Template at all, after `doc.Close` it gets unresponsive and crashes. If I keep `FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument = 0`, the document is saved without any template attached to it (there isn't any reference to a template, not even Normal.dot).

Comment: @MarianV. Is there VBA code in the document, or only in the attached template? If only in the attached template, then setting to NormalTemplate will remove the code. Do it after SaveAs, then you can perform doc.Save, followed by doc.Close. Note that a situation where the document has no template is *not a good thing* - Word wasn't designed to be used in such a manner and this can lead to problems! What this code is passing to `FileFormat` is essentially the Boolean value `True`, which will be translated to either 1 or -1, depending on how VBA is handling the conversion at this point...

Comment: There isn't any VBA code in the document that's created by the template, it's only in the template. If I switch to normal template, it doesn't run any code after that line. How could I still get it to run `doc.Save` and `doc.Close`?

Comment: At this, point, I'd have to do some testing. Could you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] (complete set of repro steps), please @MarianV.? I'm especially concerned about the ActiveX control, which I understand is running this code?